# Graphing functions in R?

Tags: r

So, I am able to use the `plot()` function in R to graph different functions. However, I am finding that the graphs in R do not typically show the entire curve of the function. Let me use an example:

```
    fun <- function(x){
        x^3 + 2*x^2 + 3*x + 4
      }
    plot(fun)
```

[image: Image in RPlot: x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x + 4]

However, when I plot the same function using the Desmos Graphing Calculator it shows all four quadrants of the Cartesian graph whereas R is only showing one:

[image: Image in Desmos: x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x + 4]

My question: How can I modify RPlot to show all four quadrants as opposed to just one as in the above case?

Answer (score 5):

I think you can do this just by extending the default range (which is [0,1]):

```
plot(fun,from=-5,to=5,ylim=c(-8,8),col="red")
grid()
abline(v=0,h=0,lty=2)
```

I've added a few frills to make it look a little more like the desired plot.  Adding a point on the y axis is easy; adding the x-intercept is not quite so easy.

```
points(0,fun(0),pch=16)
points(Re(polyroot(c(4,3,2,1))[2]),0,pch=16)
```